# "Close Tray" appears in explorer when cdrom drive is already closed

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, compact-disc, optical-drive

OS: Windows 7

CDROM drive model: WH12LS38 (actually a bluray burner)

Issue:

When right clicking on my cdrom drive letter in explorer, I expect to see "Open Tray" because the tray is already closed, but instead I see "Close Tray". No matter what I try, I can't get "Open Tray" to appear. Upon clicking "Close Tray", nothing happens.

Things I've tried:

- Having a disc in the drive or out of the drive
- Hitting the normal eject button button on the front of the drive
- Trying different media types - CDs, DVDs, CD-RWs
- Disabling the drive in device manager and re-enabling
- Upgrading the drive's firmware
- Rebooting

Any other ideas? Unfortunately, I don't have another drive to test with.

A possibly related problem is that when I stick a new CD (or DVD) in the drive, explorer often shows the contents of an old disk I previously had in the drive and **even allows me to read the contents of the files on the old disk** sometimes, even though that disk is not in the drive!! I'm assuming it's reading the data from cache in RAM. Other times, I get an error - something about the disk cannot be read - when I try to open a file which explorer says is on the disk but really isn't.

Comment: I also tried using ImgBurn to look at the contents of the disk and also to try to eject the disk. ImgBurn **always** shows the correct contents and is also able to eject the disk without any problems, so this is definitely an explorer issue.

Comment: Do you by any chance have a program installed that lets you mount ISOs on your computer, like Virtual CloneDrive?

Comment: I have had many installed at one point or another. Daemon Tools and Virtual CloneDrive that I can remember. I currently have DVDfab VirtualDrive installed. Do you have similar troubles with Virtual CloneDrive?